# openframeworks, ofThread and ofxXmlSettings (weird error)

Tags: c++, openframeworks

At the moment I have a weird error that I can't understand.

The thingie is:
I have a method in a class that creates a thread like this

```
    void loadDocument(){
            ActionThread* thread = new ActionThread(data, path);
            thread->start();
    }
```

then in ActionThread.h

```
    class ActionThread : public ofThread{

    public:
    bool toLoad;
    Data* data;
    string path;

    ActionThread(Data* data, string path){
            this->toLoad = true;
            this->data = data;
            this->path = path;
    }

    void start(){
            startThread(true, false);
    }

    void threadedFunction(){
            if(toLoad)
                    data->loadDocument(path);
            stopThread();
    }
    }
```

and in Data.cpp

```
    void Data::loadDocument(string path){
            ofxXmlSettings xmlDocument;
            xmlDocument.load(path); <------------   
    }
```

So, this is the idea of the code. The problem is when I call the method `loadDocument` twice, the second one will rise an error at `xmlDocument.load(path)`. 
The second path can be or not the same path as the first one.
Doesn´t matter what path I select for the second one, it will always raise an error saying `std::out_of_range at memory location`.
Without threads, I mean doing the `loadDocument` without any thread, it works, but I need them because some loads take a while.

Anyone here have an idea why this happens? By the way, it crashes in ofUtils.cpp at

```
    string ofToDataPath(string path, bool makeAbsolute)
```

method when it checks

```
    if (defaultWorkingDirectory().toString() != getWorkingDir().toString())
```

Comment: I figured it out. Wasnt from load -.-. Debugger said that was there, but wasn't. The beautiful world of threads make things like this :D